# Dotnetnuke 6 Ribbonbar Admin and dropdown gone

Tags: dotnetnuke, runtime-error, dotnetnuke-6

[image: example]

Above is the ribbonbar after I have logged in as a super user. The Admin option next to Host is completely gone

The site is running DNN6, the skin is only in the site portal folder, and it seems that all admin modules and options have gone away. Even the header, which I set in Site Settings (under Admin), went away!

Has anyone else had their admin options completely disappear on them? Is it possible that the skin is messing it up (all other sites use the same _default menu files and they work fine)?

Thanks for any replies.

Comment: --EDIT-- This has been solved by excising parts of the legacy skin being used. Most of it was trial and error, and I never found any root to the problem. The skin was the culprit. Thanks to animuson for the image insertion, and to Chris Hammonds for replying! Also, this would go in the original post, but I'm not allowed to re-edit without deleting animuson's inserted image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check the database to see if those pages exist? What if you try to navigate to http://website/admin.aspx do you see the admin page and all the child pages there?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. It was due to a legacy skin, but I never found out why. Your suggestion was a good idea, and it helped me discover that all child pages of admin really were missing. Well, not missing, but not being included in that specific portal due to the skin (the DNN installation still works for like 90 other sites).

Answer (score 2):

We've recently had this exact situation occur in one of our DNN sites. It turn out that one of the site's administrators had accidentally renamed the Admin page from within the "Page Management" section (it's easy to see how that could happen). The fix was to go directly to **/Admin/Pages.aspx** and change the "**Page Name**" back to "**Admin**" ... and it will show up in the ribbon bar again.

As a suggestion to DNN developers, I would recommend making the Admin page and its subpages impossible to rename....